# VBA Sum If With Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've been trying, for about a week now to put together a sheet which encompasses a 'SumIf' Formula based on a multiple criteria.

I've been able to do this, manually entering the formula with the desired results in a cell range.

The problem I have is really two fold.

- The formula I used was an array formula, but the skill level of some of my users is perhaps not as good as I would hope, so I know they won't be able to cope adding the formula themselves, so I looked at the option of using VB code,
- The problem with this is, I know you cannot use an array formula in VB, so I'm a little unsure how to proceed.

To perhaps illustrate this a little better, I've attached a file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgg17x0ogry1vh4/Extract%20Macro%20Count%20Unqiue%20Values%20Test.xls) shows what I'm trying to achieve.

- On the sheet "Slide 5", I'm would like to extract the results in the
  columns shaded orange,
- And for each cell I would like to perform the following 'SumIf':

  1. Sum the figure in the named range **"Actuals"**,
  2. If the value in named range **"JRole"** is the same as the value in row **6** of the
     **"Slide 5"** sheet, **and**,
  3. The value in the named range **"Months"** is the same as the value in cell **B3** on
     the **"Slide 5"** sheet, **and**,
  4. The value in the named range **"PLOB"** is the same as the value in the cell in
     **column K** on the **"Slide 5"** sheet.

As I say, I've been working on this for a while, but I just can't come up with a solution.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may be able to achieve this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Use Sumproduct() if you want exact solution I can post if for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to run a Sub to populate the orange fields then my code would fill in the data for you

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSolution()

    ' declaring a variable of Worksheet type for easier reference
    ' instead of saying: Sheets("All Data") you can use a shorter
    ' variable name: "data"
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Set data = Sheets("All Data")

    Dim result As Worksheet
    Set result = Sheets("Slide 5")

    ' these two variables hold the SUM for both analyst types
    ' in the loops flow
    Dim seniorAnalystSum As Double
    Dim analystSum As Double

    ' using resource and projectLob Range objects for quick reference to cells
    ' in both spreadsheets
    ' so again, instead of saying data.Range("A" & i) etc
    ' simple and short way is "resource" and/or "projectLob"
    Dim resource As Range
    Dim projectLob As Range

    ' for each cell in between K8:K16 on the result/ Sheets("Slide 5")
    ' pick up one cell at a time
    For Each resource In result.Range("K8:K16")
        ' and go over all cells between B5 and last cell in Data sheet
        For Each projectLob In data.Range("B5:B" & data.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            If projectLob = resource Then
                ' compare year and month between the matching cells
                If (Month(projectLob.Offset(0, 8)) = Month(result.Range("B3"))) And _
                (Year(projectLob.Offset(0, 8)) = Year(result.Range("B3"))) Then
                    ' compare to the row of the table that holds the type of analyst
                    If projectLob.Offset(0, 7) = result.Range("L6") Then
                        'C&R Senior Analyst
                        seniorAnalystSum = seniorAnalystSum + projectLob.Offset(0, 12)
                    ElseIf projectLob.Offset(0, 7) = result.Range("N6") Then
                        'C&R Analyst
                        analystSum = analystSum + projectLob.Offset(0, 12)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Assigns the sum for the senior analyst
        resource.Offset(0, 2) = seniorAnalystSum
        ' assigns the sum for normal analyst
        resource.Offset(0, 4) = analystSum
        ' reset both sums for the next loop
        seniorAnalystSum = 0
        analystSum = 0
    Next

End Sub
```

I have used your sample data and populated the results as follows

[image]

I hope this is the kind of solution you're looking for :) Awaiting your feedback

Comment: Hi @mehow, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for the solution. It works great and it's exactly what I was after. May I ask please, because I'm very keen to learn more about that you add some comments to the code. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM sure, I have added a few comments. Note you can add breakpoints in the code with F9 and step through it then you will be able to better visualize what is going on

Comment: Hi @mehow, thank you so very much for this. IT is greatly appreciated. I've now awarded you the Bounty. All the best and kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM no problem! Sweet, my first bounty on SO :)

Comment: Well @mehow, it was thoroughly deserved!

Answer (score -1):

Use the following formula in `SLIDE5 COLUMN M`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('All Data'!$I$5:$I$40='Slide 5'!$L$6:$M$6)*('All Data'!$J$5:$J$40='Slide 5'!$B$3)*('All Data'!$B$5:$B$40='Slide 5'!$K8)*('All Data'!$N$5:$N$40))
```

and in `SLIDE5 COLUMN O` USE THIS

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('All Data'!$I$5:$I$40='Slide 5'!$L$6:$M$6)*('All Data'!$J$5:$J$40='Slide 5'!$B$3)*('All Data'!$B$5:$B$40='Slide 5'!$K8)*('All Data'!$N$5:$N$40))
```

Juse drag the formula to the subsequent rows

Comment: Hi @Youbaraj Sharma, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Unfortunately, as I said, although I'm more than comfortable to enter the formula, there are users of this spreadsheet who would not, which is why I have been looking for an automated VB solution.

Comment: So are you looking for vba solution?, that can also be done easily. But on the easier front you can save this sheet and protect the formula so that other users can input the value in main sheet and the formula gets auto populated...they don't have to enter the formula every time. VBA can also help you to this extent only...

Comment: Hi @Youbaraj Sharma. Thank you for coming back to me with this and I appreciate your time and trouble. Yes, I can confirm that I am looking for a VB solution, if at all possible please, because this will form part of a bigger VB script which I've already written. The user won't need to enter anything into the workbook because my aim is to automate the whole process. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: just dopped and saw these comments. If there is no user that can mess with your data, why don't you play between VBA coding and values/results from Excel native functions (applied to cell values)? I do this often (usually in hidden sheets), as this can shortcut the entire process. VBA is great at this approach, not like in programming where you need to hold all your dims/variables within the code. In Excel you can put them down (in cells) apply basic functions and then pick them up again in your code.

Comment: @YoubarajSharma the formula for column doesn't work as supposed to - it only shows `0.26` in `O12` which is wrong - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301709/vba-sum-if-with-multiple-criteria/20353901#20353901) for the correct values

Answer (score -1):

quick and dirty solution

1 - Use the ***evaluate*** operator to get your expected result

```
Evaluate('SUMPRODUCT(
   ('All Data'!$I$5:$I$40='Slide 5'!$L$6:$M$6)
   *('All Data'!$J$5:$J$40='Slide 5'!$B$3)
   *('All Data'!$B$5:$B$40='Slide 5'!$K8)
   *('All Data'!$N$5:$N$40))'
)
```

2 - Use the ***Application.WorksheetFunction.Sumproduct*** function which replace the SUMPRODUCT wokrksheet function